# Arduino compatibility with unofficial modules

Tags: gps, arduino, gprs

Completely new to Arduino and am looking to really dive in. An idea I have requires a small form factor for a gsm/gprs module, something that could work with one of the micro arduinos. I can't find any sort of *really* small gprs modules.

My question:

Is it possible to use the module from an old cell phone and adapt it to arduino? Or is that an outrageous concept? I also found one that looked interesting on  ([ebay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Mini-Global-RealTime-GPS-Tracker-GSM-GPRS-GPS-Tracking-Tool-ForChildren-Pet-Car/251770975721)) would it be possible to adapt to something like that?

I am aware that it'd be a big undertaking!

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible! most of the modules [serially communicates](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/serial-communication) you only need to get the baud-rate correct.

There are examples and tutorials you can find on the internet this [Instructables tutorial](http://www.instructables.com/id/Use-your-android-phone-sensors-on-the-arduino-/) is worth seeing.